# How to get User entered text from jQuery UI combobox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am using jQuery UI Combobox and I want to get the text entered by the user.

The user entered text may or may not have the matching element in the select list.
I want to display this user entered text in the alert.

Answer (score 0):

## Correction:

Since it is a **`combox`**, you can bind it to the **`change`** event like below

```
$(function() {
         $( "#combobox" ).combobox();         
         $("#combobox").change(function() {
             alert($(this).val());  //To fetch the value                 
         });
     });
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RDj4Z/5/)

**FYI:**

1. To get *selected value* using **`$(this).val()`**
2. To get *selected option's text* **`$(this).find('option:selected').text()`**

Comment: $(this).val() works for autocomplete. But it is not working for jQuery UI Combobox.

Comment: I have checked the fiddle. Its working for autocomplete. But I want it for jQuery UI Combobox.

Comment: @praveen I misunderstood because of the tags, check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/hAM9H/984/ for jQuer UI combo box.

Comment: I have checked the updated fiddle.. This works for the value that is present in the select list of combobox (say ActionScript,Applescript). I want it for the user typed values in the combobox which may not be present in the select list (say MyActionScript).

Comment: Doesn't work. Alert doesn't fire. What browser are you using?